# Rigidbody for Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am New to unity... I am trying to solve one logic... Three Cubes in the plane if I click space first cube will jump, the second click space button the second cube will jump and third click the third cube will jump in the fourth click first cube will jump.. I have done the script for cube jump I don't how to cycle that cubes help me to solve this

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isGrounded;
    private static int count = 0;
    Rigidbody rb;
    GameObject cube1, cube2, cube3;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0f, 10f, 0f);
            cube1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player1");
            cube2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player2");
            cube3 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player3");
            isGrounded = false;

        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == ("Ground") && isGrounded == false)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to summarize you want one cube to be jumped at a time and you want to repeat the cycle right?

Comment: 1st space bar click 1st cube will jump, 2nd space bar click 2 cube will jump and 3rd space bar click 3rd cube will jump and 4th click 1st cube will jump

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would save a `List` of GameObjects inside the `Control` script and then use the objects rigidbodies to set their velocity.

```
public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int count = 0;
    public List<GameObject> cubes;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            cubes[count].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0f, 10f, 0f);
            count = (++count) % cubes.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

This script will need to be added to an empty GameObject; then you can fill the `cubes` list from the editor by dragging the cubes in it. The other cubes **do not** need the `Control` script.
Your scene graph will have these elements:

> -- Control (GameObject with Control script)
>
> -- Cube1
>
> -- Cube2
>
> -- Cube3

Comment: cube1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player1"); this line also add in this script right for identify the cube???

Comment: No. I don't understand what you mean though. Can you explain?

Comment: This Code is just fine...@Annisha if you don't want Assign GameObjects in Inspector then you have to use GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player1") code

Comment: Variables with the `public` scope or marked with the attribute `[SerializeField]` can be set in the Inspector window. Drag your cube gameobjects from the scene hierarchy onto the `cubes` variable in the inspector. You will have access to those game objects in script through that list.